# Problem calculating Work function in Photoelectric effect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

I'm having trobules understanding the solution of the following problem.
In the problem we have a solar cell, which is impacted by a green light of $\lambda = 560nm$ and, as a consequence, there is some current. When we apply a voltage of $0,95 V$ the current dissapears.
So the probelm is asking for the work function.
I've got the following:
$$hf = W_{ext} + E_{cmax}$$
And here, $E_{cmax} = qV$. So I plugged the charge of the electron, with the sign, and I got a negative sign here. So I checked the solution and I saw that here that, logically, there was no negative sign. It makes sense, because the $E_{cmax}$ can not be negative, but I'm searching for a better explanation on why here we're not using the sign of the charge.

Comment: A current of 0.95V? Do you mean a current of 0.95A or a voltage of 0.95V? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya Sorry, a typo. It's voltage.

Answer (score 0):

See, you can think of it in two ways the stopping voltage is always opposite to the electrons velocity hence it should also be given a negative sign .....second one is here the electrons works against an external field and loses its energy so work should be positive

Comment: Or may be its more of a convention since we equate ev=ke(max) if you take v as positive than u cant negative take sign of the charge